# Date manipulation on xquery 1.0

Tags: date, datetime, xquery

I have here an old version xquery where I use to fetch data from the back end server. how do I get the current date and the coming Sundays. it looks all the samples I see are for recent versions and I just couldn't use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FunctX XQuery function library](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0002.html) lists a lot of date/time functions and adds some other helpful ones. They're all for XQuery 1.0, but which functions are available for you can depend on your implementation. If your implementation supports full XQuery 1.0, following should work for you.

Have a look at [`fn:current-date`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_current-date.html).

For getting the date of the next sunday, using [`functx:functx:day-of-week`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_day-of-week.html) will help a lot. All you have to do is add the day of week to the date (and some conversions).

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"; 
declare function functx:day-of-week 
  ( $date as xs:anyAtomicType? )  as xs:integer? {

  if (empty($date))
  then ()
  else xs:integer((xs:date($date) - xs:date('1901-01-06'))
          div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) mod 7
 } ;


let $today := fn:current-date()
return
    $today + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', functx:day-of-week($today), 'D'))
```